# Having a Program wait for a click event

Tags: c#, events, click

I am looking to have a program wait for a click event to occur. This is my code for the click event. The program runs right through it. To give you context, this is an othello program, and this is for when it is a humans turn.

Sadly the program runs through it and continues and the AI player goes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {

                textboxes[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(textboxes_Click);
                textboxes[i, j].Tag = new GridIndex() { ipos = i, jpos = j };

            }
        }
```

Then I handle textboxes_Click.

Thanks for the help!
-Lewis

Comment: What you've done here is add 64 event handlers to your text box. You need to read up on the event model.

Comment: Why do you expect that the program's execution will be suspended, given the code you've shown? It will run through the `for` loop and continue to the code after it.

Answer (score 1):

That's just adding handlers to be executed *when* something is clicked (although I'm not convinced that textboxes are really the best controls to be using here).

You need to think of GUI programming in an event-based way: you don't direct the flow of control, the user does. You set everything up so that when an event occurs, you react appropriately.

So instead of making the AI player go immediately after you've set up the event handlers, you should *react* to the human player taking a turn by making the AI player go afterwards - assuming the turn was valid, of course. In other words, your event handler for reacting to the human player's turn should include logic to work out whose turn it is next, and to take the turn if it's the AI. (This general logic should be encapsulated in another method, and executed after the AI's turn too - that way you could have two computers playing against each other, or two humans, etc.)